# How to add more iterations in a for loop C# Make my loop pick up more

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am trying to show multiple things in a textbox in my software and its just printing out 1 / 5

I think I got the for loop all mixed up so here is how it looks

```
var getTopFive = new FirefoxDriver();
getTopFive.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.tradingview.com/");

IList<IWebElement> movies = getTopFive.FindElements(By.CssSelector("tbody tr"));

for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
{
    activeTextBox.Text = movies[i].Text;  
}
```

This is what I tried and failed with.

I tried adding another

```
activeTextBox.Text = movies[i].Text;
```

Which did not work

I also tried adding a second block of the same code showed at the top but with a different name for the int etc.

Then I tried adding a else if below it which gave me another error.

So my question is, how do I make the loop go through all the 5 items instead of just showing the first one which it does by this line of code right here.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
{
  activeTextBox.Text = movies[i].Text;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, as it is a well-asked question. Beginners can and do use tutorials and books, but are as dependent upon peer support as their more experienced counterparts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here. The first is your for loop is only going to happen once because `for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)`.

To loop more than once, you need to change to `1` to something else. If you want it dynamic, use `for(int i = 0; i < movies.Count; i++)`.

The second issue is `activeTextBox.Text` is being over-written each time you write to it. No matter how many times you repeat the loop or the line, the only thing that text box will show is the last item in the loop.

If you want it to show all items, you need to do something like:
`activeTextBox.Text += movies[i].Text + "\n";`

The `\n` will put each movie on a separate line - you could use a hyphen or similar to separate each item.

Comment: I tried this, it didnt put all of them on seperate lines but it added all of them so thank you! I'm going to assume that it was the += which made them add all so for example

if the item is equal(=) to 1 it says okay its the correct one lets move on and add(+) another one and loops until the 5th one?

Comment: Yes it is the `+=` which appends each movie to the text box. I thought `\n`would give it on each line but perhaps the text box doesn't support that. Hyphens should work though :-)

Answer (score 3):

*IList* has a property called *Count*. This property returns the number of elements in the list. Use it in your loop like this to show all movies:

```
for (int i = 0; i < movies.Count; i++)
{
  activeTextBox.Text = movies[i].Text;
}
```

A second way is to use a foreach loop like this:

```
foreach (IWebElement WebElement in movies)
{
  activeTextBox.Text = WebElement.Text;
}
```

Remember you are overwriting your text each loop. So in the end your text will be the last item of your loop. If you want to add the names behind each other do it like this (seperated with a minus)

```
activeTextBox.Text += " - " + movies[i].Text;
```

or this

```
activeTextBox.Text += " - " + WebElement.Text
```

clear the Text before your loop with

```
activeTextBox.Text.Clear();
```

Comment: That was a very clear and simple explanation, would you mind telling me why its We.Text, what does the "We" do?

Comment: Thank you. The We.Text was a mistake. I corrected it. Hope it helps.

Comment: as I said to the other guy
I'm going to assume that it was the += which made them add all so for example if the item is equal(=) to 1 it says okay its the correct one lets move on and add(+) another one and loops until the 5th one

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code (don't forget to add `using System.Linq;`):

```
activeTextBox.Text = string.Join("; ", movies.Select(x => x.Text));
```

**Explanation:**

`movies.Select(x => x.Text)` takes every `IWebElement` (movie) and return its `Text` property. So you end up with a list of movie names instead of `IWebElement` objects.

Next, you join those movies together into a single string, separated by semicolon. (`string.Join("; ", ...)`)

And then you assign the result to the activeTextBox.

Comment: This seems very complicated, would you mind explaining how it works? :-)

Comment: @VinnyGarcia I have added explanation to my original answer =)

Comment: Seems difficult but I guess thats a way to go! :D

Comment: Using Linq for such a simple example is unnecessarily complicated, especially for a beginner. I would recommend one of the other answers presented here.